# Change number of rows to show

Tags: datatables

In Allan Jardine's DataTables plugin, what's the option by which no. of rows to display in table can be altered?

I know about `iDisplayLength` for server-side function. I am using it successfully.
When the database has sufficient rows, it shows those many rows.

But when, for example, if I set it to 10 (rows), it should display those many rows (even if there are only 3 rows in the database & the rest 7 blank rows should be displayed).

Basically I want to control the height of table, irrespective of how many records are there in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out.
Just set this property in table initialisation

```
    "sScrollY": "100px",
```

In place of 100px, put the size as required.

Answer (score 0):

Wel one thing you could consider doing is controlling the minHeight of the class dataTables_wrapper wich is set at 302 px by default

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 302px;
    position: relative;
}
```

This usually  is enough for everyone, but if you override the settings you could set it higher.

Comment: I tried that. But no success. I have uploaded a 162kb screenshot image.   I wish to have the RHS table to be of same height of the LHS table, even if RHS table has less no. of rows.   Can you pl. see & advise.   [Click this Link to Image of dataTables](http://www.4shared.com/photo/dmqw3rip/datatables_height.html).   Thanks.